# Function pointers in C++ class constructor

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a templated class with a constructor which takes a single argument; a function pointer to a function that takes an argument of the second template-type. and returns an element of the first template-type.

Here's the code:

cache_controller.hpp:

```
template<class TYPE, class KEY>
class cache
{
    private:
        TYPE (*create_func)(KEY);
    public:
        cache(TYPE (*func)(KEY));
};

extern sf::Texture * create_texture(std::string path);
```

cache_controller.cpp:

```
template<class TYPE, class KEY>
cache<TYPE, KEY>::cache(TYPE (*func)(KEY))
{
    this->create_func = func;
}

sf::Texture * create_texture(std::string path)
{
    sf::Texture * tex_p = new sf::Texture;
    tex_p->loadFromFile(path);
    return tex_p;
}
```

Test code:

```
cache<sf::Texture *, std::string> tcache(&create_texture);
```

However, when I link I get this error:

```
[Linker error] main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cache<sf::Texture*, std::string>::cache(sf::Texture* (*)(std::string))'
```

Of course, if there are any easier ways to implement an object cache with arbitary keys, values and creation functions I'm all ears.

Comment: Note that it is more common to put the template parameters the other way around, analogous to `std::map` or other associative containers: `cache<std::string, sf::Texture*>` (key => value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide a definition for member functions of a template class in a `.cpp` file.

The definition of those member functions must be visible to the compiler at the instantiation point (i.e., from the `.cpp` file that invokes those functions), otherwise only their *declaration* will be seen, and the compiler will just rely on that function being defined somewhere else, while processing a different translation unit.

Since there is no instantiation of that function in the translation unit (i.e. `.cpp` file) where its definition is visible to the compiler, none will be generated, and the linker will eventually complain that no definition is provided.

You should put the definition of `cache`'s constructor in the header file where class template `cache` is defined (which is, in your case, `cache_controller.hpp`).

Comment: I'm an idiot for forgetting that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mloc: No worries, we've all been there.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of a templated method must coincide with the file that holds its declaration. Template instantiation is a compile-time operation, not a link-time. Merge the two into each other for the linker error to be resolved. That is, implement the constructor either inside the class or outside but within the same file.